# Searching for IP addresses in a file

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am writing a program to get an output for a user input. The user inputs an IP address, and then I need to display a specific part of the above line.

Here is the file:

> mot physical /ABC-RD0.CLD/CPQSCWSSF001f1-V.80 { 
>       poolcoin /ABC-RD0.CLD/123.45.67.890:88 
>       ip-protocol tcp 
>       mask 255.255.255.255 
>           /Common/source_addr { 
>               default yes 
>  mot physical /ABC-RD0.CLD/CPQSCWSSF001f1-V.80 { 
>       profiles { 
>           /Common/http { } 
>           /Common/webserver-tcp-lan-optimized { 
>               context serverside 
>  } 
>  mot physical /ABC-RD0.CLD/BBQSCPQZ001f1-V.80 { 
>       poolcoin /ABC-RD0.CLD/123.45.67.890:88 
>       ip-protocol tcp 
>       mask 255.255.255.255

Sample input with expected output:

> User inputs the IP and output should be: 
>  
>  user input:
>   123.45.67.890
>  output: CPQSCWSSF001f1 <---------------------------- 
>  user input: 123.45.67.890 
>  output: BBQSCPQZ001f1
>   <----------------------------

My code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re 

ip = raw_input("Please enter your IP: ") 

with open("test.txt") as open file: 
    for line in open file: 
        for part in line.split(): 
            if ip in part: 
                print part -1
```

Comment: stackoverflow provides you a nice tools for formatting a content please use them.

Comment: correct your title first.state the actual problem.

Comment: Please put some explanation about input 123.45.67.890 two times but get a different output. What is a reason?

Comment: In agreement with @terces907: Some more time researching how to elegantly format a precise question, for readability, would vastly decrease the overall time in which it takes to receive feedback.

Comment: Not many languages allow spaces in variable names (`open file`), and Python isn't one of them. Please check the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: `re.findAll(\'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})', fileContent, re.S)` ? Or better, if you can, use CLI and grep the file with regex if you don't want to open a whole file. Even compiled regex won't perform well if you have a million-line file and want to regex-match every line.

Comment: Have a look at https://regex101.com/r/jQ3zL5/1 - this gives you a tuple of string and ip addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet gives you a tuple of string/ip addresses:

```
import re

string = """
mot physical /ABC-RD0.CLD/CPQSCWSSF001f1-V.80 {
poolcoin /ABC-RD0.CLD/123.45.67.890:88
ip-protocol tcp
mask 255.255.255.255
/Common/source_addr {
default yes
mot physical /ABC-RD0.CLD/CPQSCWSSF001f1-V.80 {
profiles {
/Common/http { }
/Common/webserver-tcp-lan-optimized {
context serverside
}
mot physical /ABC-RD0.CLD/BBQSCPQZ001f1-V.80 {
poolcoin /ABC-RD0.CLD/123.45.67.890:88
ip-protocol tcp
mask 255.255.255.255 
"""

rx = re.compile("""
                ^mot            # look for mot at the beginning
                (?:[^/]+/){2}   # two times no / followed by /
                (?P<name>[^-]+) # capture everything that is not - to "name"
                (?:[^/]+/){2}   # the same construct as above
                (?P<ip>[\d.]+)  # capture digits and points
                """, re.VERBOSE|re.MULTILINE)

matches = rx.findall(string)
print matches
# output: [('CPQSCWSSF001f1', '123.45.67.890'), ('BBQSCPQZ001f1', '123.45.67.890')]
```

See [a demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/41S8RZ).
Maybe you'd be better of using `re.finditer()` and stop the execution once your ip address has been found.